# How to solve Jquery conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can you please help? I am a kind of starter in jquery i am considering to use a ready multi steps forms in my angular js / spring application so i found one through the net that i liked.

It works when i try it in the browser but not when i integrate in my web app. i have seen in other answered questions that i have to insert the noConflicts method but it doesn't seem to work.

The idea is that i have an index page in which every html page is integrated before being displayed on the browser. this index page contains many other scripts so i think it is a conflict issue, PS: I have no error in the console

here is my js script for the multisteps form:

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 800,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;

 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show();
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  },
  duration: 800,
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  },
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

i insert this  script (generationContenu.js )to the index page as follow

```html
  <!-- JQuery v1.9.1 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="static/js/jquery/generationContenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="static/js/plugins/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

the jquery.easing.min.js is also used in the multisteps form.

and the html of the multisteps form is as follow :

```html
<div class="row" ng-cloak>
  <!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
 <!-- progressbar -->
 <ul id="progressbar">
  <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
  <li>Social Profiles</li>
  <li>Personal Details</li>
 </ul>
 <!-- fieldsets -->
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
  <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
  <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
  <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
  <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
</form>

  </div>
```

can you please help?

Comment: If you suspect it's a conflict issue you can always replace all `$` with `jQuery` and see if that helps.

Comment: How does it conflict? Are you using 2 versions of jQuery? My bet is you are trying to bind events to elements that do not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, no i am using only one version but this is what i found after surfing on the net, elements that doesn't exist? the only change i do is to call the js scripts form the index in which the multisteps forms is integrated, i tried to call these scripts from the multi steps form it works but not when it is integrated in the index template.
Any Ideas?